# Why PWA Workbox doesn't always handle the same route in the same way?

Tags: javascript, networking, frontend, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I created the basic Workbox StaleWhileRevalidate strategy for my **favicon** and it should return the cached value on the request if network is offline. It works partially. 
Actually it returns the cached value only for 2 requests and other requests are failing. In the console, we can see errors about *unhandled exception* and *failed to fetch*. I'm wondering how it's possible?

The service worker handler.

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
console.log(5555); // basically works every time
  if (event.request.url.indexOf('favicon.ico') !== -1) {
    event.respondWith((async () => {
      // Configure the strategy in advance.
      const strategy = new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({cacheName: 'favicon-cache-v1'});


      // Make two requests using the strategy.
      // Because we're passing in event, event.waitUntil() will be called automatically.

      return strategy.handle({event, request: event.request.url})
        .catch(() => {
           // it's never happens somehow (propably because it's always fetch from cache, but I'm not sure
          console.log("WHOOOPSS, CATCH") 
        })
    })());
  }
});
```

As you can see, there are errors in the console about Failed favicon fetch. But how it's possible? 
Workbox should catch it, it prints **'5555'** debug message and it should return the cached favicon for all requests. But it does it only for 2 requests and other requests are failing. Why does it happen?
[image: Console errors]

The Chrome Devtool Network report  (Network is offline)
[image: network report]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working as expected. The two requests from your client app to the service worker are successful because you have the assets cached. The two requests to update the cached asset from the service worker to the server fail because the network is offline.

Comment: Hi Abraham. Thank you for the good notice. I didn't know it, now it's clear to me.